# How to find/generate a 6 variable Bent Function?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I want to find a Bent Function with 6 variables.
I read some papers about how to generate Boolean Functions, but I don't want to implement an algorithm from zero just to find one function.
It is also quite easy to test wether a function is Bent or not. But since Bent Functions are very sparse in 6 dimensions, it will take a long time to find a Bent Function with random (or heuristic) search.

I also searched for something like a database for Boolean/Bent functions, but could not find any.
I just need one (random) Bent Function, how can I find one ?

Answer (score 1):

I found 4 6-variable Bent functions:

I took the screenshot a while ago, so I do not remember the source.

[image: 6-variable bent functions]

Comment: The source is the [full version](http://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2096&context=infopapers) of the paper [HAVAL — A one-way hashing algorithm with variable length of output](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-57220-1_54), whose extended abstract was published in the proceedings of *Advances in Cryptology — AUSCRYPT '92*.